# When updating the emission of a shader, it only updates when I click in the editor [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

So I have this shader that I am trying to make flicker, so I am making the emission value go back and forth between 0 and 1, but it only works if I click on the material or scroll in the editor. I can't figure this out, help please?

I checked something similar to this, but it still won't work, so please help.

```
Renderer renderer;
Material material;
float emission;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    material = renderer.material;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    emission = Mathf.PingPong (Time.time, 1f);
    Color color = Color.red;

    Color finalColor = color * Mathf.LinearToGammaSpace (emission);
    material.SetColor ("_EmissionColor", finalColor);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved a problem like you 
pleas share your Shader to us thanks

try Mathf.sin(Time.time) to get pingpong maybe your problem Solved

or 
use blow shader

```
Shader "Custom/Emition" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _EmissionColor ("Bright", Float) = 1.0
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200
        pass {
        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma vertex vert            
        #pragma fragment frag

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"


        uniform float _EmissionColor;
        sampler2D _MainTex;
        struct vertexInput {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;          
            float2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct vertexOutput {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float2 uv  : TEXCOORD0;
        };


        vertexOutput vert(vertexInput input)
        {
            vertexOutput output;
            output.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,  input.vertex);

            output.uv = input.texcoord;
            return output;
        }

        float4 frag(vertexOutput input) : COLOR
        {   
            fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex , input.uv) ;



            /// change blow line 


            return c* float4(_EmissionColor,1,1,1);

        }
        ENDCG
    } 
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: Fragment shaders is safe and havent anybug